# Using Eloquent relationships gives 'Call to undefined method'

Tags: laravel-4

In Laravel's docs there is example that shows how one can chain relationships between Models.

```
// one to many relationship
$comments = Post::find(1)->comments;
```

So this is how you can retrieve all the comments, for post with id 1.

But why I can't use relationships chained with `where`, I keep getting

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::classifieds()
```

Here's my code:

```
$classifieds = ClassifiedCategory::where('slug', 'like', $slug)
                                ->classifieds()
                                ->where('is_approved', 'true')
                                ->get();
```

And here's the related code from ClassifiedCategory model:

```
public function classifieds() {
 return $this->hasMany('Classified');
}
```

Comment: So which records are you trying to get from that query? I can read your query in different ways..

Comment: I want to fetch all classifieds that belongs to some classified category, and which are approved. I know how to do it using standard JOIN, but I'm not sure how to do that with Eloquent and relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whereHas` can be used, but here's why your code doesn't work and how to make it work:

```
$classifieds = ClassifiedCategory::where('slug', 'like', $slug)
    // here you are trying to call relation before you fetched the model
    ->classifieds() 
    ->where('is_approved', 'true')
    ->get();
```

So you need:

```
$classifieds = ClassifiedCategory::where('slug', 'like', $slug)
    ->first() // fetch the category
    ->classifieds()  // now query the relation
    ->where('is_approved', 'true')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `whereHas`:

```
$classifieds = Classified::where('is_approved', 'true')
                        ->whereHas('classifiedCategory', function($q) use($slug) {
                            $q->where('slug', 'like', $slug);
                        })
                        ->get();
```

Assuming you have the inverse relationship also defined.

```
public function classifiedCategory() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Classified');
}
```

Comment: Good, but closure lacks `use ($slug)` and the relation should point to `ClassifiedCategory`.

Comment: Yes, that's true, although I was curious to do that starting from ClassifiedCategory. Thanks for helping!